# gcov not detecting correct kunit tests

Tags: unit-testing, linux-kernel, gcov

I started to work on a series of unit tests for different kernel modules I am currently writing. To that goal, I am using the the excellent KUnit framework.

Following the simple test described on the KUnit webpage, I was able to create a first test series that compiles, runs and displays the results as expected.

For me the next step was to use code coverage on those results to generate a report of the quality of the coverage of the testing strategies on the different modules.

The problem comes when I open the results of the code coverage. It indicates that no lines have been parsed by my tests in the module I am writing. I know for a fact that this is not the case because I generated in the test function a failed test using:

`KUNIT_FAIL(test, "This test never passes.");`

And kunit.py reports that the test failed. Even the source code for the test was not reported as being covert...

Does someone have a idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the answer to my own question, hoping this will help someone in the same situation.

There were two issues:

1. The GCC version (as stated in the documentation of Kunit) must be inferior to 7.xx
2. The code coverage for kunit is available starting at 5.14.

Once I used gcc 6.5.0 and a 5.15 kernel, followed the manual in kunit for code coverage, everything worked as hoped!